# What are all of the types of equipment I can find in the campaign

Tags: starcraft-2, nova-covert-ops

During the campaign's 9 missions what equipment can I expect to find.

I want to make sure that I haven't missed any.

Thanks

Comment: No one has updated the wikis yet, but as a quick reference you can use optional objectives - missable gear is rewarded for those. If you have "all optional objectives completed" achievement unlocked, you should have all the gear.

Comment: The main reason I asked is I found a gunblade weapon which was unmarked, and easily missable.

Comment: Wiki was [updated](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Nova_Terra_(Nova_Covert_Ops)#Loadouts).